# How make Crystal Reports honor sort order

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

how to get the data in the order same as in backend in a crystal report?

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more information than this. Examples of the data, what database system, and a detailed description of the issue.

Comment: From what I remember Crystal cannot do this; you need to specify a sort order within the Crystal report itself.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Kieren Johnstone said above, Crystal ignores the order of the records as they come from the data source.  You will need to set the sort order in Crystal itself.

If the sort setup changes based on some parameter in the back end, and there is no easy way to let crystal know about this change, then one solution is to supply crystal with a column of data that can always be trusted to produce the correct sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Default when you execute any sql query, database gives you rows in no perticular order. You can use order by to sort though.

Comment: The problem Aparna is experiencing is that Crystal is not retaining the order from the backend, though